# Writting My lightweight MVC framework

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

I have planned to write my own light weight MVC for PHP, that will be used as base for my sites I develop. I have no problem with PHP, OOP, et al. I have trouble on how to actually load Models In controllers and use them amd loading Controller values into Views. In short, I don't know how M-V-C interact behind the scenes.
Any tutorial (concentrating on that) or any contribution is welcomed!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After google and check how other MVC works I decided to take this route. I redirect all my requests with .htaccess to index.php. Then there I define base paths. After all the definitions I include the core.php which in turn includes all core files to my mvc framework. Then in the same file I create Instances of Registry and router and the game starts from here!

Internals are a bit complex now but that is what I ended with!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is open source: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

**Edit:** consider this: I believe you are trying to reinvent the wheel, thinking that those MVC framework out there are heavy and packed with uncessary features *(acording to your double use of the word lightweigth)*. In my experience, I always ended up coding those extra "features" because a framework is required to evolve. *Loading models In controllers, using them and loading controller values into views* is just the begining. If you want to get started eventually, it would be a better investment to write some helper classes and methods: a popular pattern in the MVC world. Unless you are writing a MVC framework from scratch for fun and I am totally wrong *(you said you needed a* **base** *to use for your site***s** *)*.

Best of luck!

Comment: Mh! I know nothing of ASP, except that it is M$ thing :)

Comment: If M$ is giving their MVC framework chances are good that you find an open source PHP MVC framework! :)

Comment: Yeah, and yes I want to reinvert the wheel a little for sake of learning and have simple framework when I begin each site. I use CI too!

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is an open source MVC framework of php.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

The major in MVC is first of all your controller class initiated and then calls view.

Comment: Thanks, I use too CI. But I wanted to make simple skeleton of MVC framework for Quick non-complicated works. and Oh! I want to learn too :)

Comment: The simplest way working in MVC is creating your view first and All logic in Business logic layer and then DBLayer just call your business logic calls from view classes.